# Manually correct git commit hashes

Tags: git

Scenario: coworker A is doing work on their feature branch. I fork their repository and do work based on their feature branch. Coworker A amends a single commit, thus changing its hash.

Since I know the commit in my branch that is equivalent to the commit in coworker A's branch; is there a way that I can just replace my commit with theirs so that our histories merge correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like one of the scenarios where `git cherry-pick` will save your life. You move your changes on top of the new revision that your coworker has (with cherry-pick), set your private branch to the new end result revision and move on.

Answer (score 0):

You should rebase your local edits. To automatically skip commits which already were existing in remote branch you can use `--fork-point` option:

```
git rebase --fork-point origin/branch
```

To be extra sure you could add `-i`  option and verify the commit list